# Algorithm For Determining Sentence Subject Similarity

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, markov-chains

I'm looking to generate an algorithm that can determine the similarity of a series of sentences. Specifically, given a starter sentence, I want to determine if the following sentence is a suitable addition.

For example, take the following:

> My dog loves to drink water.

All is good, this is just the first sentence.

> The dog hates cats.

All is good, both sentences reference dogs.

> It enjoys walks on the beach.

All is good, "it" is neutral enough to be an appropriate communication.

> Pizza is great with pineapple on top.

This would not be a suitable addition, as the sentence does not build on to the "narrative" created by the first three sentences.

---

To outline the project a bit, I've created a library that generated Markov text chains based on the input text. That text is then corrected grammatically to produce viable sentences. I now want to string these sentences together to create coherent paragraphs.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://allmybrain.com/2007/10/19/similarity-of-texts-the-vector-space-model-with-python/ or what do you have tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [semantic similarity between sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037832/semantic-similarity-between-sentences)

Comment: I'm looking more for conceptual similarities in terms of subject matter. The linked resources appear to match semantics.