# How to Compare two sentences semantically?

Tags: android, nlp, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I am trying to build an app for college so the students can have their exams on it 
but I am having problem the article questions which I can't compare the answer of the student and the answer of the model answer to check if it was right or wrong 
so can anyone help me with that or tell me where to start ?
I have read about a lot of algorithms but I don't know where to begin.

I have found codes and function but I don't know how to use them like the following link [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037832/semantic-similarity-between-sentences)

Comment: Hey Yasser, adding code snippet related to specific issues would be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should generate average vector for each answer. Then, you can compare this vectors with lots of method. It's easily, vectoral distance or cosine similarity can be used. Each words will have a vector by using Word2Vec. After you must calculate average vectors.

Maybe, you want to look this project about  [grading open-ended questions](https://github.com/suleymanbalaban3/AnswerGradingWithLSTM)