# finding semantic similarity between 2 statements

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am currently working with small application in **python** and my application has search functionality (currently using **difflib**) but I want to create **Semantic Search** which can give top 5 or 10 results from my database, based on user inputted text. It is same as google search engine works. I found some solutions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037832/semantic-similarity-between-sentences).

But the problem is, below two statements from one of solution are semantically incorrect. And I don't care about this. because they are making things too hard which I don't want And also solution will be some pretrained neural network model or library from which I can implement easily.

- Pete and Rob have found a dog near the station.
- Pete and Rob have never found a dog near the station

And also I found some solutions which are showing using `gensim` and `Glove` embeddings and finding similarity between words and not sentences.

## What I wanted ?

Suppose my db has statement `display classes` and user inputs `show`, `showed`, `displayed`, `displayed class`, `show types` etc are same. And if above 2 statements are given as same then also I don't care. `displayed` and `displayed class` already showing in difflib.

## Points to be noted

- Find from fixed set of statements but user inputted statements can differ
- Must work for statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is not `gensim` embedding. It is `word2vec` embedding. Whatever it is.

## You need tensorflow_hub

The **Universal Sentence Encoder** encodes text into `high-dimensional vectors` that can be used for `text classification`, `semantic similarity`, `clustering` and other natural language tasks.

I believe you need here is **Text Classification** or **Semantic Similarity** because you want to find nearest top 5 or 10 statements given statement from user.

It is easy to use. But size of model is ≈ 1GB. It works with **words, sentences, phrases or short paragraphs.** The input is variable length English text and the output is a 512 dimensional vector. You can find more information about it [Here](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4)

### Code

```py
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np

# Load model. It will download first time.
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5" 
model = hub.load(module_url)

# first data[0] is your actual value
data = ["display classes", "show", "showed" ,"displayed class", "show types"]

# find high-dimensional vectors.
vecs = model(data)

# find distance between statements using inner product
dists = np.inner(vecs[0], vecs)

# print dists
print(dists)
```

### Output

```sh
array([0.9999999 , 0.5633253 , 0.46475542, 0.85303843, 0.61701006],dtype=float32)
```

### Conclusion

First value `0.999999` is distance between `display classes` and `display classes` itself. second `0.5633253` is distance between `display classes` and `show` and last `0.61701006` is distance between `display classes` and `show types`.

Using this, you can find distance between given input and statements in db. then rank them according to distance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `wordnet` for finding synonyms and then use these synonyms for finding similar statements.

```py
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

nltk.download('wordnet')

def get_syn_list(gword):
  syn_list = []
  try:
    syn_list.extend(wn.synsets(gword,pos=wn.NOUN))
    syn_list.extend(wn.synsets(gword,pos=wn.VERB))
    syn_list.extend(wn.synsets(gword,pos=wn.ADJ))
    syn_list.extend(wn.synsets(gword,pos=wn.ADV))
  except :
    print("Something Wrong Happened")
  syn_words = []
  for i in syn_list:
    syn_words.append(i.lemmas()[0].name())
  return syn_words
```

Now use `split` and split your statements in db. like this

```py
stat = ["display classes"]

syn_dict = {}
for i in stat:
   tmp = []
   for x in i.split(" "):
       tmp.extend(get_syn_list(x))
   syn_dict[i] = set(tmp)
```

Now you have synonyms just compare them with inputted text. And **use lemmatizer before comparing words so that `displayed` become `display`**.

Comment: But how to compare these inputted text to this dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can use `spacy`

This answer is from https://medium.com/better-programming/the-beginners-guide-to-similarity-matching-using-spacy-782fc2922f7c

```py
import spacy

nlp =  spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")

doc1 = nlp("display classes")
doc2 = nlp("show types")
print(doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

## Output

```sh
0.6277548513279427
```

### Edit

Run following command, which will download model.

```sh
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg
```

Comment: Hey When I installed spacy and run above code I got error `Can't find model 'en_core_web_lg'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.`

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Keep in mind, that while links are welcome, all posts on SO must be self-contained, in case the content of the page changes, or the link becomes unavailable. Also user experience suffers when users are *required* to hop aground the web to piece together an "answer". Simply include any relevant explanations from the link into your post. In this way, UX is great, and links provide a welcome addendum for follow up, confirmation, or deeper dives.

Comment: @FocusNow I updated solution. Your issue is solved.