# calculate similarity between two lists of tags

Tags: python, nlp, nlu

How can I calculate the semantic similarity between two lists of tags?
For example:

**Input**

```
list1 = ['marketing', 'social medial', 'operations', 'management']
list2 = ['software development', 'system network', 'system design']
```

**Ouput**

```
5%
```

Are there any python packages/libraries I can use to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding semantic similarity between 2 statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62131293/finding-semantic-similarity-between-2-statements)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/two-lists-similarity/

Comment: @RJAdriaansen  `two-list-similarity` seems to text similarity but not semantic similarity. But this would still be helpful.Thank you.

Comment: @WaseemRandhawa, thank you. I think the 3 answer from that post seems to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot calculate the "semantic similarity", only the degree of overlap of the two lists. You have two lists of arbitrary elements and want to see how similar the lists are with each other.

There are several metrics to do that, eg the [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) or the [Sørensen–Dice coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8rensen%E2%80%93Dice_coefficient). Either of these should work for your purposes.

This assumes thast the elements in your lists are arbitrary, but for your example the similarity would be zero, as there is no overlap at all. If you want to look at the similarity of the terms, you need a different approach.

For that you'd need to work out the pairwise similarity of two terms, and you could then substitute those for equality in the corresponding metrics.